# invalid syntax when using self.size = size

Tags: python

super, super new to Python and programming in general. I have a question that should be simple enough. I'm using a python beginners programming book using Python version 3.1.

I am currently writing out one of the programs in the book and I am learning about how important indentation is when using python so I was fixing those errors I found and then I get to where I put `self.size = size` and it highlights that `self` in the code block is *invalid syntax* but I'm typing this word for word from the manual so I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the code block:

```
def _init_(self, x, y, size):
    """ Initialize asteroid sprite. """
    super(Asteroid, self)._init_(
    image = Asteroid.images[size],
    x = x, y = y,
    dx = random.choice([1, -1]) * Asteroid.SPEED * random.random()/size,
    dy = random.choice([1, -1]) * Asteroid.SPEED * random.random()/size

    self.size = size
```

The problem is that last line, it highlights self as invalid syntax but nothing else... Also one last note, when I put this particular block into the shell and try running it there it also gives me a syntax error but not the same one, it gives me one right after the colon on the first line of this block and highlights that entire blank area with red.....and I can't figure why. I was putting it in shell so it could highlight the self thing and help me, but instead shows me something completely different.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: it should be `def __init__`, with double underscores, not `_init_`.

Comment: surely you are missing a round bracket, end of the "dy=" line

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to close the parentheses.

Usually, when you forget to close some parentheses, the interpreted points the error as being in the following line:

```
def _init_(self, x, y, size):
    """ Initialize asteroid sprite. """
    super(Asteroid, self)._init_(    <-- here you have a parentheses opening
        image = Asteroid.images[size],
        x = x, y = y,
        dx = random.choice([1, -1]) * Asteroid.SPEED * random.random()/size,
        dy = random.choice([1, -1]) * Asteroid.SPEED * random.random()/size  <-- no more commas here

    self.size = size  <-- first line without a trailing comma OR parentheses: SYNTAX ERROR HERE! (even though the assignment itself is ok)
```

Perhaps what the book actually meant was this - as Martijn Pieters pointed out, some of the `self.__init__` parameters (`x` and `y`) are being passed to the parent's `__init__` method, for which other parameters are being read elsewhere (`image`) or created on-the-fly (`dx` and `dy`). Finally, one of the parameters (`size`) is passed only to the instance, in the body of `self.__init__`, assigning to `self.size`:

```
def __init__(self, x, y, size):
    """ Initialize asteroid sprite. """
    super(Asteroid, self)._init_(
        image = Asteroid.images[size],
        x = x,
        y = y,
        dx = (random.choice([1, -1]) * Asteroid.SPEED * random.random()/size),
        dy = (random.choice([1, -1]) * Asteroid.SPEED * random.random()/size))

    self.size = size
```

It is important to know that any method (routine defined inside a class) in Python receives a first argument automatically, which is the object instance itself. Although you might call it what you want, `self` is the universal Python convention for that. So, when you define `__init__` and pass `self`as first parameter, you can use it throughout this function to refer to the object you are creating. Thus, saying `self.x = x` means you want the object to have a `x` attribute, its value being the `x` argument you passed upon object creation.

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend you to read "Learning Python", from O'Reilly, it has a light language (with lots of silly jokes and references), making you really understand "what's going on" with the way Python works. It has helped me a lot, being by far the most accessible AND complete Python learning resource I've had opportunity to read.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help so far. I think with the information you guys have provided me I can troubleshoot it now! Its annoying how in programming its always the little things you miss :P.